# Sending Images from PowerApps to Microsoft Flow

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

Is it currently possible to send a captured image from PowerApps to Microsoft flow?

The basic idea of the app is to take a picture with the camera control then pass the image to a Microsoft flow which will then send an email with the image as an attachment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a summary of steps. Links to video and article are in the end.

1. Add camera control and a button to save the camera capture. So set `OnSelect` of your button to be:

   ```
   UpdateContext({CameraPhoto: Camera1.Stream})
   ```
2. Go to Microsoft flow and search template "PowerApps upload file to SharePoint". Give information of where to save in SharePoint in the first two lines. Click "..." in top right corner and select "setting". Click "Cancel". Change "File Content" to:

   ```
   dataUriToBinary(triggerBody()['CreatefileFileContent'])
   ```
3. Go back to Powerapps, add a button and `OnSelect` will be:

   ```
   UploadimagetoSPO.Run("amyname.jpg",CameraPhoto)
   ```

Here is an [article](https://www.techmikael.com/2017/05/an-even-more-clever-workaround-for.html) and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ovLIwnj6QjU) of this tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use the JSON() function to pass the image to PowerAutaomte as string.

Then you just add it to the mail body like this

```
<img src=”data:image/jpeg;base64,.......” alt=”CompanyLogo” />
```

where the passed data goes into the src attribute.